# Wordpress: Load CSS and JS only on page where shortcode is used

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I want to show the css and javascript files only when the shortcode (embedyt) is used in a certain page.

I'm not an expert in php but I need to modify some things in my wordpress site.

This is the css and js file:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='__EPYT__style-css'  href='***/wp-content/plugins/youtube-embed-plus/styles/ytprefs.min.css?ver=13.4.1.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' defer src='***/wp-content/plugins/youtube-embed-plus/scripts/ytprefs.min.js?ver=13.4.1.2' id='__ytprefs__-js'></script>
```

This is the code I've insert in my function.php (child) but does not work

```
function youtubeembed_css_js() {
    global $post;
    
    if( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'embedyt') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('youtube-embed-plus');
     wp_enqueue_style('youtube-embed-plus');

    }else{
        wp_dequeue_script( 'youtube-embed-plus' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'youtube-embed-plus' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'youtubeembed_css_js', 100);
```

How I can solve?
Thank you for the help

Comment: You need to register script and then enqeue script wherever necessary. check below code snippet

Comment: You don't seem to have registered 'youtube-embed-plus' so WP wont know which script to enqueue or dequeue. Look at the definition of the enqueue functions in the Wordpress Codex and also how to use wp_register_script() If you do the normal linking in the head then I doubt WP will know that it's the same script - you need to use its own functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register script first. This will not load the script.

```
<?php
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "myscripts");
function myscripts() { 
    wp_register_script('myfirstscript', 
                        get_template_directory_uri() .'/myscript.js',   //
                        array ('jquery', 'jquery-ui'),                  //depends on these, however, they are registered by core already, so no need to enqueue them.
                        false, false);
}
?>
```

To load the script, you need to use wp_enqueue_script with the script handle like shown below

```
<?php
add_shortcode('foo','my_shortcode');
function my_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    wp_enqueue_script('myfirstscript');
    ?> <HTML> <here> ... <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you for help.
But I'm very newby so I tried step by step

But I did something wrong because I still see the file in the html.

Comment: enclose above given code snippet in `<?php` `?>`

Answer (score 0):

thank you for help.
But I'm very newby so I tried step by step

I did something wrong because I still see the file in the html.

I register with this code

```
add_action('init', 'register_style');
function register_style() {
    wp_register_style( 'youtube-embed-plus', plugins_url('/styles/ytprefs.min.css', __FILE__));
    wp_register_script( 'youtube-embed-plus', plugins_url('/scripts/ytprefs.min.js', __FILE__));
}
```